# Laravel search in nested relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have problem with my search engine in Laravel. I have 3 models: Post, Comment and CommentUser.

My relations are: Post has many comments and comment has one user. I want create search for this relationship. Now I have following code:

```
$posts = Post::where('page_id', Auth::user()->page)
            ->with([
                'comments' => function($q) use($sort, $search) {
                    if($search){
                        $q->where('content', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                    }
                    if($sort == 'answered'){
                        $q->where('answered', '=', 1);
                    }
                    if($sort == 'new'){
                        $q->where('answered', '=', 0);
                    }
                },
                'comments.user' => function($q) use($sort, $search) {
                    if($search){
                        $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                    }
                },
            ])
            ->whereHas('comments', function($q) use($sort, $search){
                if($search){
                    $q->where('content', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                }
                if($sort == 'answered'){
                    $q->where('answered', '=', 1);
                }
                if($sort == 'new'){
                    $q->where('answered', '=', 0);
                }
            })
            ->orWhereHas('comments.user', function($q) use($search){
                if($search){
                    $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                }
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
            ->paginate(10);
```

I try using next with and orWhereHas but isn't working because for example when I have comment content like "best regards" I don't have user with this name or lastname and vice versa. I want search search posts where comment content is like search term or posts where user name or lastname is like search term but now two options are disclaims.

Comment: If you get rid of the eager loading part, does it work then?

Comment: Also, have you tried replacing those `whereHas...if` parts with just `when($condition) ... return $query->where(etc)` because I'm not sure you can add to the query twice inside one `whereHas` (eg if both $sort and $search are truthy)

Comment: @NicolasGoosen I don't understand, can you give me more info?